# ParseUser.getCurrentUser() freezes application

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using `(ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {}` to check if the user is Anonymous, but in some cases (on the first app start if I delete the app data) my application freezes when I try to access `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`.

I've enabled the local datastore, maybe it has something to do with it.

My application class:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, home.class);

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

*EDIT*
i call the getCurrentUser() on my splashscreen oncreate

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {

            userisloggedin = false;
        }

}
}
```

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends Application {
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, home.class);   
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

}
}
```

Comment: For more context, could you add the code where you're actually calling `getCurrentUser()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `getCurrentUser()` is not making any network calls?

Comment: added code where i call getCurrentUser() thanks!

Comment: additional inforamation: if i remove the line Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext()); start the application all works fine, add the line Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext()); again all works fine. so the problem is only if the cache / data of the app is deleted and i start the app for the first time...

Comment: @nikola would that be bad if getcurrentuser make a network call?

Comment: @markus Yes, as you can notice if data is cached it doesn't hangs. I don't know Parse SDK indepth but my gut says it does make network call, therefore it hangs the UI thread. Set StrictMode and see if it does make network calls on UI thread. If the above turns out true, use callback overloaded method or move it in worker thread.

Comment: @markus I mean not bad, but bad if it is on main thread. :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Parse.initialize(..) should be called before doing enabling the datastore. Try using 'this' instead of 'getApplicationContext()' when enabling dstastore